# How to test a spring postmapping? (Junit)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, http, junit

Im trying to test a sample post where you have a endpoint called /message which is a path parameter on localhost. The message is a var so if I post /samplemsg as an example it should print that. However Im not quite sure how to test the post. Here's what I've managed to do so far

```
@RestController
@Component
@RequestMapping(path = "/message")
public class HomeController {
    @PostMapping(path="/message")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> postName(@PathParam ("message") @RequestBody String message) {
        URI location = URI.create(ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().buildAndExpand(message + " was created").toUriString());
        return ResponseEntity.created(location).build();
    }
```

Test Class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes= RunApplication.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
class RunApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test
    void sendPost() throws URISyntaxException {
        final String baseUrl = "http://localhost:8080/message";
        URI uri = new URI(baseUrl);

        String message = "sample msg";

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.set("X-COM-PERSIST", "true");

        HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(message, headers);
        ResponseEntity<String> result = this.restTemplate.postForEntity(uri, request, String.class);

        Assert.assertEquals("sample msg was created", result.getBody().toString());
    }

}
```

Error Message:

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<[sample msg was created]> but was:<[{"timestamp":"2022-02-14T21:54:29.152+00:00","status":404,"error":"Not Found","path":"/message/"}]>
Expected :sample msg was created
Actual   :{"timestamp":"2022-02-14T21:54:29.152+00:00","status":404,"error":"Not Found","path":"/message/"}
```

Comment: Hi there, it will be useful to see what is the result you are getting from your current code. Any error message? Any assert error ?

Comment: Updated it @JorgeCampos

Comment: So your test is working is just that you are checking (with assert) for the wrong result. Your endpoint is returning a json result saying that the endpoint you called does not exists, 404 means not found.

Comment: Im not sure why its saying path doesn't exist. I specified the path as /message in my postmapping and in the baseUrl

Comment: You may be missing `@RestController` annotation on your Controller. As the error message is looking for path "/name/" for some reason

Comment: It also depends on how your `TestRestTemplate` is configured, maybe it is adding a default path to controllers ?

Comment: As @JorgeCampos pointed out you are missing the `@RestController` annotation. This will result in all of the functions with `@RequestMapping` annotation to be ignored as you are missing the `@Controller`. Furthermore, you cannot inject anything to this class since it is not a `@Component`.

Comment: Im still getting the same error even after adding the changes

Comment: Can you please show me an example of this test as I have been stuck on this for quite a while

Comment: Now that you changed it a few points. 1 - you don't need `@RestController` and `@Component` RestController internally is annotated with `@Controller` which is annotated with `@Component`. 2 - When using `@RequestMapping(path = "/message")` at the controller class you are defining any endpoint of that controller to be prefixed with that path, since your method is mapping the end point to `/message` your final endpoint is `/message/message` either use that on your test or remove the `RequestMapping` from your class.